# write a rolling sd function in R and implement in C++

Tags: c++, r

I have to write implement R function for C++. for e.g I am trying to calculate rolling SD but below code is not working. any help will be highly appreciated.
#Below code is working fine

```
library(roll)

n <- 150
x <- rnorm(n)
x
weights <- 0.9 ^ (n:1)
weights
roll_sd(x, width = 5)
```

#But when I am passing it though the CPPFunction it is not working

```
cppFunction("roll_sd(x, width = 5)")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how `cppFunction` works. You cannot simply pass it an R call and expect it to magically transpile to C++.

In fact, it's more like the other way round. You write the function in C++ and `cppFunction` makes that function available in R.

A crude implementation of a rolling standard deviation that matches `roll_sd` would be something like this:

```r
cppFunction("NumericVector rolling_sd(NumericVector x, int width) {
   NumericVector y = clone(x);
   for(int i = 0; i < (int)x.size(); i++) {
     if(i < (width - 1)) {
       y[i] = NA_REAL;
     } else {
        double sum = 0.0;
        double total = 0.0;
        for(int j = i - (width - 1); j <= i; j++) {
          sum += x[j];
        }
        
        double mean = sum / width;
        
        for(int j = i - (width - 1); j <= i; j++) {
          total += pow(x[j] - mean, 2);
        }
        y[i] = sqrt(total / (width - 1));
      }
   }
   return y;
}")
```

After we run this code, the function `rolling_sd` is now available to us in R, and gives the same result as `roll_sd`:

```r
set.seed(1)

x <- rnorm(10)

roll::roll_sd(x, width = 5)
#> [1]        NA        NA        NA        NA 0.9610394 1.0022155 1.0183545
#> [8] 0.8694145 0.6229882 0.6688342

rolling_sd(x, width = 5)
#> [1]        NA        NA        NA        NA 0.9610394 1.0022155 1.0183545
#> [8] 0.8694145 0.6229882 0.6688342
```

However, our C++ version is over 10 times faster, as the following benchmark shows.

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(roll_sd(x, width = 5), rolling_sd(x, width = 5))
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                      expr  min   lq   mean median   uq   max neval cld
#>     roll_sd(x, width = 5) 38.7 41.4 44.310   42.2 44.3 154.5   100   b
#>  rolling_sd(x, width = 5)  2.1  2.6  3.346    3.3  3.7  15.0   100  a
```